# Angular 12 Material Multi-Select wont unselect a programmatically selected value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular 12 Material Multi-select that gets values populated through a rest call.  Then a second api call retrieves the users stored search preferences to populate the multi-select.  I am able to programmatically select the value(s) but when I try to unselect it, the value remains selected and triggers the onSelectionChange, which would be expected.

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="eventSearchGroup" novalidate>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Regions</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="RegionDD" multiple #regionDD [compareWith]="compare">
              <div class="options">
                <mat-option
                  *ngFor="let region of filteredRegions | async"
                  [value]="region.id"
                  (onSelectionChange)="onRegionChange($event)"
                  >{{ region.orgname }}</mat-option
                >
              </div>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
          ...
       </form>
```

component.ts

```
      eventSearchGroup: FormGroup;
  searchCtrl = new FormControl('');
  selectedOpArea: string = '-1';
  gridPref: UserSearchPreferences;
  mstrOpAreaList: OrgLvlDropDownListModel[] = [];
  filteredOpAreas: Observable<OrgLvlDropDownListModel[]>;

 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.createForm();
     this.getOpAreas();
     this.getSearchPref();
  }

createForm() {
         this.eventSearchGroup = new FormGroup({
           ...
           OpAreaDD: new FormControl(),
           ...
        });
      }

getOpAreas(regionid: string = '-1') {
     let endpoint = `${this.baseEventSearchController}/GetOperatingAreas`;
     let queryString = `?sourcesystem=${this.SourceSystemId}&regionId=${regionid}`;

     this._apiDataService
       .get<OrgLvlDropDownListModel[]>(endpoint, queryString)
       .pipe(
         map((response) => {
           return response;
         }),
         takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
       )
       .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<OrgLvlDropDownListModel[]>) => {
         this.mstrOpAreaList = response.body as OrgLvlDropDownListModel[];
         this.filteredOpAreas = this.searchCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
           startWith(''),
           map((value) => this._filter(value || '', this.mstrOpAreaList!))
         );
       });
   }


getSearchPref() {
    let endpoint = `${this.baseUserPrefController}/GetUserGridSearchPref`;
    let queryString = `?sourcesystem=${this.SourceSystemId}&SapId=${this.user}`;

    this.resetFilters();

    this._apiDataService
      .getSingle<UserSearchPreferences>(endpoint, queryString)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe(
        (response: HttpResponse<UserSearchPreferences>) => {
          this.gridPref = response.body as UserSearchPreferences;

          console.log('this.gridPref SEARCH: ', this.gridPref);

          if (this.gridPref) {
            if (this.gridPref.opareaid) {
              this.eventSearchGroup.patchValue({ OpAreaDD: this.gridPref.opareaid.split('|') });
            }
          } else {
            console.log(`NO SAVED PREF FOUND FOR ${this.user}`);
          }
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error(
            'get _apiDataService => EventsListComponent => loadGridSearchPref ',
            err.message
          );
        }
      );
  }

  compare(c1: { name: string }, c2: { name: string }) {
    return c1 && c2 && c1.name === c2.name;
  }


onOpAreaChange(a: MatOptionSelectionChange) {
let values: string[] = this.eventSearchGroup?.controls.OpAreaDD.value || ([] as string[]);
if (a.isUserInput) {
  if (a.source.selected && !values.includes(a.source.value)) {
    values.push(a.source.value);
  } else if (!a.source.selected && values.includes(a.source.value)) {
    values = values.filter((value) => value !== a.source.value);
  }
  this.eventSearchGroup?.controls.OpAreaDD.setValue(values);
  this.opAreaItems.emit(values);
  this.selectedOpArea = this._sharedFunctionsService.convertArrayToString(values);

}
  }
```

I have tried various examples found in SO but I can't quite work my way through it.  ANyone have any insights?

Comment: The question is not clear, What is that exactly you are looking for?